# urls not overlapping -- How to fix

Tags: django, django-urls

I am trying to filter products either by brand or category but the url path will only execute  `path('<slug:brand_slug>/', views.product_list,name='product_list_by_brand'),` since it appears first and would not execute the second.

Is there a way I can probably merge both paths or cause both paths to work independently without taking order into consideration.

```
from . import views

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),

    path('<slug:brand_slug>/', views.product_list,name='product_list_by_brand'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list,name='product_list_by_category'),
]
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your upper url pattern is overriding second URL because of same slug and some other reasons.

**FIX**

change your URL pattern

```
path('<slug:brand_slug>/brand/', views.product_list,name='product_list_by_brand'),
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list,name='product_list_by_category'),
```

**Another Thing You Can Do!**

modify your function and url pattern.

```
def product_list(request, slug):
    mode = request.GET.get("mode")

    if mode.lower() == "brand":
        ''' your brand code '''
        pass
    else:
        ''' your category code '''
        pass
```

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.product_list,name='product_list_by_category'),
```

if you want to execute brand code your URL pattern would look like this.

```
127.0.0.1:8000/yourslug?mode=brand
```

and with this url pattern it will execute category code.

```
127.0.0.1:8000/yourslug
```

so by default it will execute category code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response ... It worked

Comment: @workkofy if my answer is helpful to you. you should accept my answer it's great for me.

Comment: Thank you @HamzaLachi